# when does the process enters ready queue for CPU scheduling algorithm?

Tags: operating-system, job-scheduling

while performing scheduling algorithm the process is said to be arrived in ready queue on specified arrival time

is there any way to determine when the process will arrive in ready queue

or we can only tell when process is arrived

thank you

Comment: Would you like to give a warm welcome. ? jokes apart .. why do you need to see it ?

Comment: Certainly the scheduler knows exactly when it added a process to it's queue. But I don't see at all how is your abstract question useful and practical [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: actually while proposing an fuzzy based cpu scheduling algorithm i must know the order in which the process is arrived

Answer (score 0):

If The process is running and then does some I/O and blocks then the scheduler picks another process to run and when the blocked process completes it's I/O it moves to the ready queue and generates an interrupt to notify the cpu, and the scheduler chooses to run the now ready process or do something else.

Comment: @xmojmr A.Tannenbaum OS design and implementation 3rd, processes chapter... the question is not 100% clear so I cant answer it 100% clear too, but you seem to be smart so try to provide an answer by yourself,and correct me if I'm wrong. thanks.

Comment: I won't try to provide an answer as I was voting to close this question as unclear and not practically useful. You seem to be smart and at the same time new community member, just saying that even Stack Overflow [guru](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) says "_Provide links to related resources_", see [Jon Skeet's coding blog: ANSWERING TECHNICAL QUESTIONS HELPFULLY](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/)